# Wired connection recognized but no internet access

Tags: 16.04, internet, connection, wired

Let me start by saying, I'm very new to all of this and not as tech savvy as I'd like to think. So,  if you ask me to show you specifics,  I may not immediately now how to show you.

Anyway, I built my very first computer yesterday. I had heard good things about Ubuntu from my friends that use Linux so I decided to give it a try. Besides,  a small donation versus $200 was no contest. The installation went fine but it wouldn't recognize my wired connection. After hours of going through forums I finally got it to connect. Although, if I mess with it at all, it disconnects and I have to restart my computer. I opened Firefox and there was no internet. I opened the other browser that comes pre-installed and nothing. I went through a few similar threads but didn't find anything that worked. Or maybe my brain was just exhausted.

Here's what I'm using:
Gigabyte 990FX-UD3 R5 motherboard 
AMD FX 9590 Black Edition pcu
2 Sapphire Nitro R9 390 gpu's
16 GB RAM 
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
I didn't install a wireless card because I planned on using a wired connection

I would appreciate any help. I won't mind if you talk to me like a 3 yr old.

Comment: What do you know about your network?  I presume you are at home and have a router handling your broadband connection, right?  Can you show me the output of the terminal command `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: Your MB's chipset is tricky and one of those with a broken IOMMU. Apparently you have to edit Grub and include *iommu=soft* and at UEFI either turn on or off the IOMMU feature, depending on the model. Also depending on the model is the amount of non-working devices without the aforementioned tweak, it can range from only the USB3.0 ports not working to USB ports, Ethernet and Audio.